# Publishing website via IIS load error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi everyone when I run my project via IIS I get this error as you can see at below

```
Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 


Line 20:       <assemblies>
Line 21:         <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
Line 22:         <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
Line 23:         <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
Line 24:         <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />


Source File: C:\Users\furkan\Desktop\WebCity\WebCity\web.config    Line: 22 

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.
```

Comment: Looks like you haven't deployed all the required files, perhaps.

Comment: How can i deploy dll file on my project ?

Answer (score 1):

Allright mates I found the solution. When you get this error you have to check your missing dll files where located in bin file.

The first way is:

```
Microsoft.Web.Infastructure
System.Web.Helpers
System.Web.Mvc
System.Web.Razor
System.Web.WebPages
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment
System.Web.WebPages.Razor
```

you can find these dll files from C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages then you have to copy dll files to your project bin folder.

Second way is

Open your project in Visual Studio then click the references which names are

```
   Microsoft.Web.Infastructure
    System.Web.Helpers
    System.Web.Mvc
    System.Web.Razor
    System.Web.WebPages
    System.Web.WebPages.Deployment
    System.Web.WebPages.Razor
```

change the "Copy Local=True" from properties